# How can I use a batch file to launch an application as a specific user?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to figure out how I can use a batch file to launch Internet Explorer as a local user on the system hosting the batch file. Ideally I'd like to be able to double click the batch file and not have to enter user credentials. To break it down a bit:

User is logged onto the host system with a domain user (Server 2008 R2 Standard 64bit)

User can then double click on a batch file that will launch Internet Explorer as a local user on the host system, without prompting for the local user credentials

All I can find is information about NET USE, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

"runas" command was intentionally designed to prompt for password. So, that is not your solution.

One of option is to create a scheduled task where you can store the password (safely) and run the scheduled task from batch file.
But if the batch file is distributable and not going to be run on same machine.. you may have to investigate on how to create a schedule task from batch file and then run it.
you may find this [reference helpful](http://www.howtogeek.com/51236/how-to-create-modify-and-delete-scheduled-tasks-from-the-command-line/)

Comment: That's true, I was sure I had used it and specified a password, but my memories were incorrect :o\ I have removed my answer. Good point.

Comment: A useful suggestion, on the surface. It turns out that getting a scheduled task to run under a specific user in server 2008 R2 is near impossible. I've tried everything in this thread (http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservermanager/thread/d47d116e-10b9-44f0-9a30-7406c86c2fbe) and it just doesn't work. Does anyone else have any ideas? I'm stuck. :(